# How to get class (Index) serial number of clicked button

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

I need help!

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="myButton" value="Button1">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="myButton" value="Button2">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="myButton" value="Button3">
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="myButton" value="Button4">
```

Comment: JS: function myFunction() {
      var button = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton");
      var index;
      for (var i = 0; i < button .length; i++) {
        button[i].onclick = function() {
        index = i;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var array = document.getElementById('wrapperDiv');

for (var i = 0, len = array.children.length; i < len; i++) {

  (function(index) {
    array.children[i].onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("indexOfEl").innerText = index;
    }
  })(i);

}
```

```html
<div id='wrapperDiv'>
  <input type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="myButton" value="Button1">
  <input type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="myButton" value="Button2">
  <input type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="myButton" value="Button3">
  <input type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="myButton" value="Button4">
</div>
<p>Element index is: <span id="indexOfEl"></span></p>
```